# How to use "Point Separate" without losing edges?

Tags: geometry-nodes

When I use "Point Separate" on an object, the edges disappear:

[image: A set of Geometry Nodes, including a Point Separate node with a Mask that checks whether x>y]

[image: Blender viewport, showing the vertices from one side of a subdivided plane that has been cut in half diagonally]

Is there a way I can use the Mask function of the Point Separate node without losing the edges in the mesh?

Answer (score 0):

With Blender 3+ you can solve it relatively easily in this way:

[image]